# PHP: separate value in array according to alphabate order

Tags: php, arrays

i want to find values in array according to alphabate and want to make list in of array values according to alphabate order.

my array is like that:

> Array (
>       [0] => Array
>           (
>               [0] => Adidas
>               [1] => AKG
>               [2] => Apple
>               [3] => Barrats
>               [4] => Canon
>               [5] => Dell
>               [6] => Dixons
>               [7] => HTC
>               [8] => Liverpool
>               [9] => Microsoft
>               [10] => Pirelli Tyres
>               [11] => 
>           )
>
> )

and i want to make a list of values according to alphabate like this:

```
A           
________        
  Adidas       
  AKG
```

plz any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could use some optimization, but does exactly what you asked:

```
    $a = array("Chicken","Fish","Hello","Lebowski","What","hey","foo");

    asort($a);
    $alphaArr = array();

    foreach(range('A', 'Z') as $letter) {

        // create empty array at offset for current letter
        $alphaArr[$letter] = array();

        foreach($a as $item) {

            // if the first letter starts with current letter
            // push it into subarray
            if (substr(strtolower($item),0,1) == strtolower($letter)) {
                $alphaArr[$letter][] = $item;
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($alphaArr);
```

Comment: @downvoter - What is the problem? Did you check the output? It is considered polite to explain why you down-voted, you know.

Comment: soory bass ..
i dont vote down.

i vote up..
sory if any mistake by me,,

Answer (score 1):

You're after [asort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)

```
asort($a);
foreach($a AS $v) {
    echo $v . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hardly comprehensible question, but I think you are looking for [`sort`](http://php.net/sort).

Answer (score 0):

$fruits = array("lemon", "orange", "banana", "apple"); 
sort($fruits); 
reset($fruits); 
while (list($key, $val) = each($fruits)) { 
   echo "fruits[".$key."] = ".$val."\n"; 
}

Answer (score 0):

Your array is already sorted.

Get hold of the inner array and then loop over the values.

Whenever the first letter changes you know its the next letter.

Comment: ya, my array is already sorted ..
bt i want to make list of values contain array according to alphabate
A
_____
abc
apple
acco

like this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resort the list by the first letter of the company name, here's one way:

```
$sorted = array();
foreach($companies as $company) {
    $sorted[ strtoupper($company{0}) ][] = $company;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just sort your array using `sort()` function and then print it out.
To have these letter captions just substr first letter and then compare to previou one:

```
$old='';
foreach ($words as $name) {
  if ($name[0] != $old) {
    echo $name[0]."<hr>\n";
  }
  echo $name."<br>\n";
  $old=$name[0];
}
```